# Centered scalable image (for extremely simple web)

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm building a coming soon website and I want to make it simple - one image in the dead center of the page, scalable to different browser sizes. Im trying to google it but none of the solutions give me the result I want. Using max-width gives weird results because I'm using negative margins in pixels so when the image scales those margins dont apply.

The image I want centered is 700x700 px.

Any help welcome :)

This is my current page: http://jsfiddle.net/EYL5U/

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: table
}

img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 700px;
height: 70px;
margin-top: -350px;
margin-left: -350px;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

It doesn't scale when I resize my browser...

Comment: some snippets or fiddle may help!

Answer (score 4):

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4AVmJ/)**

Comment: It centers it, but I doesn't scale it when I shrink the viewport

Comment: You can add `max-width:100%;max-height:100%;` for that. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4AVmJ/2/

Comment: This works, the only problem I see is when I try your jsfiddle locally it squeezes the image when I shrink the browser horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using css media query:

```
img {
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto;
        top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
        max-width: 640px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (max-aspect-ratio: 1920/1200) {
    img {
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto;
        top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 400px) and (min-aspect-ratio: 1920/1200) {
    img {
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto;
        top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

In my example image has 1920x1200 dimesnions, so you obviously need to adjust ratio and sizes to your image.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/A4rWW/

Comment: Doesn't scale proportionally in my Chrome or FF...it squeezes the image horizontally...and I haven't seen tables in years :) but thank you none the less :)

Comment: Tables are still easiest way to achieve middle vertical align :) I have new solution, check it out